# geth install in kali linux throws a error

Tags: go-ethereum, ppa

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum

PPA name not found
Utility to add PPA repositories in your debian machine
/usr/sbin/add-apt-repository ppa:user/ppa-name

Answer (score 2):

This isn't related to Ethereum.

It's due to your Kali installation not having the correct `apt`-related packages installed.

You'll need to install them first. There are [various](http://www.stormshadow.tk/2017/01/fix-add-apt-repository-in-kali-linux.html)<sub>1</sub> [articles](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/02/21/kali-linux-add-ppa-repository-add-apt-repository/)<sub>2</sub> on the internet on how to do this. Alternatively, add the PPA [by hand](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22693/how-to-manually-insert-a-repository-in-source-list).

Or... just download the pre-built binaries from the [Downloads](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/) page.

Comment: (Having said this, I'm sure that when Kali was [BackTrack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BackTrack), there were some mechanisms in place to make adding PPAs deliberately difficult, presumably for security reasons... )